# adding a feature that formats a code in a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, formatting

I am creating my own blog.

I would like to add a feature enabling the users to format code (based on the wanted langage) before posting.

My blog is being written with Ruby on Rails.

How can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ckeditor you can download as a gem:

```
gem install ckeditor
```

Which you can then drop in to rails - [documentation](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)

Since you're using rails, it's super easy to make it safe to drop into a database without worrying about XSS scripting attacks.

It's also highly customizeable, so if there are certain things you don't want your users to (easily) be able to style through the GUI, you can customize the menu items that show up. In fact, you're probably pretty familiar with CKEditor - years ago it was known as FCKeditor. The functionality you'll get is similar to the text editing features you see here on stackoveflow.

Comment: does ckeditor enable me to format code (like coloring the java or uby etc)?

Comment: that's a little different - CKEditor will let your users edit text (Like we're doing right here), but styling code after they've written it is called syntax highlighting. I'd suggest looking at [Ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/syntax_highlighting) for a list of gems/plugins you can use in rails to do some syntax highlighting for display, after users have used CKEditor to submit code/text snippets.

Answer (score 0):

use ckeditor gem or direct javascript ckeditor plugin